# Secure Master Password In Xamarin Forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Can any one suggest me the best way to secure master password  and use it for encryption and decryption purpose without saving master password ?

Comment: You could get the master password from an online source (from the Azure Key Vault, for example). Here's and Azure Key Vault example: https://learn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/azure/key-vault/secrets/quick-create-net

Comment: @Michal Divis  any other workaround is der rather azure?

Comment: you can also hard code the password. But that would be visible of someone decompiled the binary... There are definitely alternatives to Azure Key Vault if that's what you mean.

Comment: i mean can we use Xamarin Essential Secure Plugin or Using Keystore  or storing in application memory ?

Comment: The Xamarin Essentials Secure Storage should do the job